# Intellij tomee set tomee.serialization.class.whitelist

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ejb, apache-tomee

How to setup in IntelliJ IDEA VM options.

**I need to setup**

```
set JAVA_OPTS="-Dtomee.serialization.class.whitelist=" 
set CATALINA_OPTS="-Dtomee.serialization.class.blacklist=-"
```

In run/debug configuration for my local tomee server I pass into VM options

```
-tomee.serialization.class.whitelist=*
-tomee.serialization.class.blacklist=-
```

also tried without *.
It still giving me "invalid arguments" error after run/debug the server. How to set it properly?

ps.If I run the server manually everything works correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the two properties as Java system properties (-D) in the VM options of your run configuration:

```
-Dtomee.serialization.class.whitelist=*
-Dtomee.serialization.class.blacklist=-
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set them in idea.exe.vmoptions (should be in bin directory of idea installation) to force it for client side and in conf/system.properties of the tomee instance for the server.